# How do I convert a string to a list of Maybe Int

Tags: haskell

How would I go about converting a string like this `"13.2..2"` to a list like this

`[Just 1, Just 3, Nothing, Just 2, Nothing, Nothing, Just 2]`

I have had a look at `digitToInt` but it does not take care of `Maybe Int`. Is there a way I could maybe modify `digitToInt` to handle `Maybe Int`?

Comment: Why all the close/down votes? This is definitely not "too broad" and it's pretty clear what's being asked.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you would like all non digits to be converted to `Nothing`, you can use guards and `fmap`

```
import Data.Char

charToMaybeInt :: Char -> Maybe Int
charToMaybeInt  x 
 | isDigit x = Just $ digitToInt x
 | otherwise = Nothing

main = putStrLn $ show $ fmap charToMaybeInt "13.2..2"
```

Using guards is, from my non-expert understanding, a bit more idiomatic than using `if`/`else`.

Comment: Why would you use `fmap`? I'm getting the same result using `map`.

Answer (score 7):

You can use `isDigit` to test whether `digitToInt` will succeed.

```
λ> fmap (\c -> if isDigit c then Just (digitToInt c) else Nothing) "13.2..2" :: [Maybe Int]
[Just 1, Just 3, Nothing, Just 2, Nothing, Nothing, Just 2]
```

We can introduce a new function to clean this up a bit:

```
digitToIntMay :: Char -> Maybe Int
digitToIntMay c = if isDigit c then Just (digitToInt c) else Nothing

λ> fmap digitToIntMay "13.2..2" :: [Maybe Int]
[Just 1, Just 3, Nothing, Just 2, Nothing, Nothing, Just 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're certain the data coming is definitely a digit or `.` (or are happy with exceptions being thrown if the data is different), you can use pattern matching and `fmap`

```
import Data.Char

chatToMaybeInt :: Char -> Maybe Int
chatToMaybeInt '.' = Nothing
chatToMaybeInt  x  = Just $ digitToInt x

main = putStrLn $ show $ fmap chatToMaybeInt "13.2..2"
```

Comment: two answers ?!? why not the two merged into one ?

Comment: @StephaneRolland Because they're different: they use different code, language features and have different pros/cons. For example, this one can throw exceptions, which the OP/voters might not find desirable. From what I can tell, multiple answers _is_ acceptable https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice.